# Ignore case UITextField/UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview

I would like to ignore all case sensitivity to be ignored for my UITextField and UITextView. I would also like to know how to detect if the string is upperCase or lowerCase. Thanks.

Comment: Write in some more detail. Are you trying to do case insensitive compare? What do you mean by detect lowercase and uppercase? What if a string contain both uppercase and lowercase letter?

Answer (score 2):

[myString uppercaseString] will give you the myString variable transformed to use only uppercase letters, [myString lowercaseString] will give you the lowercase version, respectively.

You can use it to check for uppercase (lowercase) strings like this:

```
if ([[textField text] isEqualToString:[[textField text] uppercaseString]]) {
    NSLog("String is uppercase!");
}
```

If you have a reference string and want to compare it ignoring the case, you can just use caseInsensitiveCompare: method of NSString:

```
[referenceString caseInsensitiveCompare:[textField text]];
```